# vb.net oledbdataadapter formats field to integer instead of double

Tags: vb.net, oledbdataadapter

I load a CSV file using the oledbdataadapter in Visual Studio 2005. The problem I have is if the value of the first row is 0 of any given field, the oledbdataadapter converts this field to an integer. It will round all subsequent values to an integer removing the decimal points. As a test, I manually opened up csv with notepad and changed the first row to 0.0 instead of just 0 and then the file opened up correctly making the field a double. What is the correct way to open up CSV and format fields to double?

Here is the opening code:

```
Sub LoadDB2Graph(ByVal DaFilename As String)
    Dim DaTable As String
    Try
        MyDataAdapter.Dispose()
        dsPressScope.Tables.Clear()
    Catch e1 As Exception
    End Try
    MySelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & DaFilename & "] WHERE [Time] <> 0"
    MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = MySelectCommand
    Try
        Call DeleteTestLine(1)
        Call DeleteTestLine(2)
        DaTable = Replace(DaFilename, ".", "_")
        MyDataAdapter.Fill(dsPressScope, DaTable)
        dgPressScope.DataSource = dsPressScope
        dgPressScope.DataMember = DaTable
        dgPressScope.Refresh()
        ZedGraph.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear()
        InitializeTestLines()
        ZedGraph.GraphPane.Title.Text = DBDirectory & DaFilename
        ZedGraph.GraphPane.AxisChange()
        tabMain.SelectTab("tbSelectPens")
        Me.Text = "Press Scope - " & DBDirectory & DaFilename
    Catch e1 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Load Failed")
    End Try
    LoadPens2List()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using MyDataAdapter.FillSchema(dsPressScope, SchemaType.Source, daTable) right before you do MyDataAdapter.Fill?

Comment: I figured the answer is in the schema.ini, but I don't know what what the fields are going to be before I open it. Can you change it after you open it?

Comment: Also, I have hundreds/thousands of csv files scattered throughout different PC's and different directories with files being constantly added. Do I have to go through the trouble of adding a schema.ini for everyone of these files? I was looking for something easier...

Comment: The schema is read from the source; no need for a .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the file **schema.ini**

With this file, format documented by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you could specify a set of information that supplements your connection string when a text driver is involved in the data access operations

For example you could write a schema.ini like this:

```
[data.txt]
Format=Delimited(;)
MaxScanRows=0
Col1=ID Integer
Col2=ProductName Text Width 100
Col3=Price Double
```

This assumes that your text file is called Data.txt and is composed of three columns Integer, Text and Double. The file should be saved in the same directory where your text files resides.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6) class to load CSV files instead of using the `OleDbDataAdapter` class.  Doing so will give you more control over the whole process.

For instance, you could do something like this:

```
Using reader As New TextFieldParser("my csv file Path")
    reader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
    reader.SetDelimiters(",")
    While Not reader.EndOfData
        Try
            For Each field As String In reader.ReadFields()
                Dim value As Double = 0
                If Double.TryParse(field, value) Then
                    ' Process this field value
                Else
                    ' Handle the invalid value
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As MalformedLineException
            ' Handle exception ...
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Can you load this into a dataset?

Comment: Yes, you can create a new, empty DataSet, add a new DataTable to it, add columns to the table, and then you can add rows to the table using those columns.